# Optimization of a function in R ( L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn')

Tags: r

I would like to optimize (maximum) of the following function `f1`. I wrote the following code which using the lower and upper bound, since  we know that all of our parameters are equal or bigger than zero and also we always should have `x4` values less than or equal `x6`. How can I fix this problem in R?I want to get a finite maximum value of function `f1`.

```
          x1 = 0.1
          x2 = 0.1
          x3 = 2
          x4 = 10
          x5 = 2
          x6 = 30
          x7 = 1
          par = list(x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3, x4=x4,x5=x5, x6=x6, x7=x7)
          par1 = c(1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1)

          f1 = function(x, par){
              sum(log(exp(-(par$x7)*(par$x1*x + par$x2*x^2/2 + 
                par$x3 * (par$x4-x)^3/3+par$x5 *(x-par$x6)^3/3))))
          }

         x = seq(0, 500, length=100)
         z = c(par$x1, par$x2, par$x3, par$x4, par$x5, par$x6, par$x7)

        f2 = function(z){
            par.new = list(x1 = z[1], x2 = z[2], x3 = z[3], x4 = z[4]
           , x5 = z[5], x6 = z[6], x7 = z[7])
           f1(x, par.new)
        }

      optim(par1, f2, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0, length(z)),
      upper = rep(Inf,length(z)),control = list(trace = 5,fnscale=-1)) 
      > optim(par1, f2, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0, length(z)), 
        upper = rep(Inf, length(z)), control = list(trace = 5,fnscale=-1))
        N = 7, M = 5 machine precision = 2.22045e-16
        L = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       X0 = 1 1 2 1.5 1 1.5 1 
       U = inf inf inf inf inf inf inf 
       At X0, 0 variables are exactly at the bounds
       Error in optim(par1, f2, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0, length(z)),  : 
       L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

Comment: `f1(x,par)` depends on the parameter vector, but also on a variable `x`. So are you trying to find the value of `x` which maximizes `f1` for a given set of parameters, or are you trying to find a set of parameters which maximize `f1` for a given `x`? Or is it something else??

Comment: @jilhoward. I am trying to find a set of parameters which maximize f1 for a given x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some point in the optimization, your function is returning a value greater than `.Machine$double.xmax` (which is `1.797693e+308` on my machine).

Since your function `f1(...)` is defined as `sum(log(exp(...)))`, and since `log(exp(z)) = z` for any z, why not use this:

```
par1 = c(1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1)
x = seq(0, 500, length=100)
f1 = function(par, x){
  sum(-(par[7])*(par[1]*x + par[2]*x^2/2 + 
                           par[3] * (par[4]-x)^3/3+par[6] *(x-par[7])^3/3))
}
result <- optim(par1, f1, x=x, 
                method = "L-BFGS-B", 
                lower = rep(0, length(par1)), upper = rep(Inf,length(par1)),
                control = list(trace = 5,fnscale=-1)) 

result$par
# [1] 2.026284e-01 2.026284e-01 8.290126e+08 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 9.995598e+35 2.920267e+27
result$value
# [1] 2.423136e+147
```

Note that the vector of parameters (`par`) must be the *first* argument to `f1`.