# R impute with Kalman on large data

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, data-manipulation, imputation

I have a large dataset, 4666972 obs. of 5 variables.
I want to impute one column, `MPR`, with [**Kalman** method](https://rdrr.io/cran/imputeTS/man/na_kalman.html) based on each groups.

```
> str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4666972 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Year : int  1999 2000 2001 1999 2000 2001 1999 2000 2001 1999 ...
 $ State: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CC   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ID   : chr  "1" "1" "1" "2" ...
 $ MPR  : num  54 54 55 52 52 53 60 60 65 70 ...
```

I tried the code below but it crashed after a while.

```
> library(imputeTS)
> data.table::setDT(dt)[, MPR_kalman := with(dt, ave(MPR, State, CC, ID, FUN=na_kalman))]
```

I don't know how to improve the time efficiency and impute successfully without crashed.

Is it better to split the dataset with `ID` to list and impute each of them with `for loop`?

```
> length(unique(hpms_S3$Section_ID))
[1] 668184

> split(dt, dt$ID)
```

However, I think this will not save too much of memory use or avoid crashed since when I split the dataset to `668184` lists and impute, I need to do multiple times and then combine to one dataset at last.

Is there any great way to do or how can I optimize code I did?

I provide the simple sample here:

```
# dt
Year  State   CC   ID    MPR    
2002     15   3     3     NA  
2003     15   3     3     NA  
2004     15   3     3    193   
2005     15   3     3    193  
2006     15   3     3    348  
2007     15   3     3    388  
2008     15   3     3    388  
1999     53   33    1     NA  
2000     53   33    1     NA       
2002     53   33    1     NA      
2003     53   33    1     NA   
2004     53   33    1     NA     
2005     53   33    1    170  
2006     53   33    1    170        
2007     53   33    1    330      
2008     53   33    1    330
```

**EDIT**:
As @r2evans mentioned in comment, I modified the code:

```
> setDT(dt)[, MPR_kalman := ave(MPR, State, CC, ID, FUN=na_kalman), by = .(State, CC, ID)]

Error in optim(init[mask], getLike, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

I got the error above. I found the [post](https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS/issues/26) here for this error discussions. However, even I use `na_kalman(MPR, type = 'level')`, I still got error. I think there might be some repeated values within groups so that it produced error.

Comment: Using `data.table` and embedding `with(dt, ...)` inside of it is a bit anti-idiomatic of `data.table`'s intended methodology. Have you tried just `...[, MPR := ave(MPR, ...)]`? (The anti-pattern stems from opportunities and efficiencies that DT does well such as `,by=.(somegroup)`, etc, where the `with(dt, ...)` will fail.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps splitting should be done using `data.table`'s `by=` operator, perhaps more efficient.

Since I don't have `imputeTS` installed (there are several nested dependencies I don't have), I'll fake imputation using `zoo::na.locf`, both forward/backwards. I'm not suggesting this be your imputation mechanism, I'm using it to demonstrate a more-common pattern with `data.table`.

```r
myimpute <- function(z) zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(z, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Now some equivalent calls, one with your `with(dt, ...)` and my alternatives (which are really walk-throughs until my ultimate suggestion of `5`):

```r
dt[, MPR_kalman1 := with(dt, ave(MPR, State, CC, ID, FUN = myimpute))]
dt[, MPR_kalman2 := with(.SD, ave(MPR, State, CC, ID, FUN = myimpute))]
dt[, MPR_kalman3 := with(.SD, ave(MPR, FUN = myimpute)), by = .(State, CC, ID)]
dt[, MPR_kalman4 := ave(MPR, FUN = myimpute), by = .(State, CC, ID)]
dt[, MPR_kalman5 := myimpute(MPR), by = .(State, CC, ID)]
#     Year State CC ID MPR MPR_kalman1 MPR_kalman2 MPR_kalman3 MPR_kalman4 MPR_kalman5
#  1: 2002    15  3  3  NA         193         193         193         193         193
#  2: 2003    15  3  3  NA         193         193         193         193         193
#  3: 2004    15  3  3 193         193         193         193         193         193
#  4: 2005    15  3  3 193         193         193         193         193         193
#  5: 2006    15  3  3 348         348         348         348         348         348
#  6: 2007    15  3  3 388         388         388         388         388         388
#  7: 2008    15  3  3 388         388         388         388         388         388
#  8: 1999    53 33  1  NA         170         170         170         170         170
#  9: 2000    53 33  1  NA         170         170         170         170         170
# 10: 2002    53 33  1  NA         170         170         170         170         170
# 11: 2003    53 33  1  NA         170         170         170         170         170
# 12: 2004    53 33  1  NA         170         170         170         170         170
# 13: 2005    53 33  1 170         170         170         170         170         170
# 14: 2006    53 33  1 170         170         170         170         170         170
# 15: 2007    53 33  1 330         330         330         330         330         330
# 16: 2008    53 33  1 330         330         330         330         330         330
```

The two methods produce the same results, but the latter preserves many of the memory-efficiencies that can make `data.table` preferred.

The use of `with(dt, ...)` is an anti-pattern in one case, and a strong risk in another. For the "risk" part, realize that `data.table` can do a lot of things behind-the-scenes so that the calculations/function-calls within the `j=` component (second argument) only sees data that is relevant. A clear example is grouping, but another (unrelated to this) `data.table` example is conditional replacement, as in `dt[is.na(x), x := -1]`. With the reference to the enter table `dt` inside of this, if there is ever something in the first argument (conditional replacement) or a `by=` argument, then it fails.

`MPR_kalman2` mitigates this by using `.SD`, which is `data.table`'s way of replacing the data-to-be-used with the *"`S`ubset of the `D`ata"* ([ref](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-sd-usage.html)). But it's still not taking advantage of `data.table`'s significant efficiencies in dealing in-memory with groups.

`MPR_kalman3` works on this by grouping outside, still using `with` but not (as in `2`) in a more friendly way.

`MPR_kalman4` removes the use of `with`, since really the `MPR` visible to `ave` is only within each group anyway. And then when you think about it, since `ave` is given no grouping variables, it really just passes all of the `MPR` data straight-through to `myimpute`. From this, we have `MPR_kalman5`, a direct method that is along the normal patterns of `data.table`.

While I don't *know* that it will mitigate your crashing, it is intended very much to be memory-efficient (in `data.table`'s ways).

Comment: akrun, I'm assuming you mean `tidyr::fill`, not to be confused with `data.table::fill`, not clear in your comment. Also, the question is specific about `data.table`, not `tidyverse`. Lastly, the `myimpute` function was purely (and specifically mentioned as) demonstrative as a place-holder, because I'm being too lazy to install `imputeTS` and all of its (nested) dependencies. Insert any function you want there, but since the OP was about `na_kalman`, my hope is that this will work with that imputation device without change.

Comment: sorry, i meant tidyr:fill.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your solution but I replaced the `myimpute` function to `na_kalman` in `ave()` without using `with()`. However, I got error. I modified above.

Comment: PeterChen, according to https://stackoverflow.com/q/23718161/3358272 and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-June/165751.html, that error message suggests that the imputation is returning non-finite values. Are you saying that something works using `with(dt, ave(...))` but the same thing fails without `with`? Does it fail with the sample data you provided above? (I apologize for not having `imputeTS` installed for direct testing, it might be that my answer does not address the actual underlying problem, regardless of my `data.table`-centric recommendations.)

Comment: It worked fine on sample data so that it's my fault. But not sure why it returned non-infinite values. I think it might due to the repeated values within some groups.

Comment: That's a hard one to track down, honestly. That kind of problem is likely either a mathematical singularly (or some other theoretical problem), an implementation problem, or (unlikely but possible) a mistaken assumption with the data. Sorry, though, if you can only reproduce the problem with the whole dataset, it's going to be difficult to troubleshoot here. Bummer.