# Error in optim: L-BFGS-B needs finite value of fn

Tags: r, imputation

I am trying to run **impute_errors()** function of the **imputeTestBench** package for a series of values. I am using six user defined methods for selection of best imputation method. Below is my code:

```
    correctedSalesHistoryMatrix[, 1:2],
    matrix(unlist(apply(X = as.matrix(correctedSalesHistoryMatrix[, -c(1, 2)]),
                        MARGIN = 1,
                        FUN = impute_errors,
                        smps = "mcar", 
                        methods = c(
                          "imputationMethod1"
                          , "imputationMethod2"
                          , "imputationMethod3"
                          , "imputationMethod4"
                          , "imputationMethod5"
                          , "imputationMethod6"
                        ), 
                        methodPath = "C:\\Documents\\Imputations.R",
                        errorParameter = "mape",
                        missPercentFrom = 10,
                        missPercentTo = 10
                        )
                  ), nrow = nrow(correctedSalesHistoryMatrix), byrow = T
           )
    )
```

When I am using a small dataset, the function executes successfully. When I am using a large dataset I am using the following error:

> Error in optim(init[mask], getLike, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0,  :
> L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
> Called from: optim(init[mask], getLike, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = rep(0,
> np + 1L), upper = rep(Inf, np + 1L), control = optim.control)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an easy fix.

Error is probably not caused by `imputeTestBench` itself, but rather by one of your user defined imputation methods.

Run `impute_errors` like before and only add `na_mean` as method instead of your user defined methods (`impute_errors(..., methods = 'na_mean')` ) to see if this suggestion is true.

The error itself occurs quite often and has to do with `stats::optim` receiving inputs it can't deal with. Quite likely you are not using `stats::optim` in your user defined imputation methods (so you can't easily fix the input). More likely is that a package your are using is doing some calculations and then using `stats::optim`. Or even worse a package you are using is using another package, that is using `stats::optim`.

In the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718161/optimization-of-a-function-in-r-l-bfgs-b-needs-finite-values-of-fn) you can see an explanation underlying problem. Overall seems to occur especially for large datasets, when the `fn` input parameter to `stats::optim` becomes `Inf`.

Here a some examples of the problem also occurring for different R packages and functions (which all use stats::optim somewhere internally): [1](https://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/02ax19gt0d/r-structts), [2](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Time-Series-smoothing-td899514.html), [3](https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS/issues/26)

Not too much you can do overall, if you don't want to go extremely deep into the underlying packages.

If you are using the `imputeTS` package for one of your user supplied imputation methods, in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS/issues/26) a workaround is proposed, which might help, if the error occurs within the `na_kalman` or `na_seadec` method.