# Error in optim(par = Tm1, fn = .logLgam, x = x) : object 'Tm1' not found

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to run the `MSClaio2008` function of the `nsRFA` library in R. Following the documentation, I have successfully run the examples given on the web site. However, when I created my own data set to run with the `MSClaio2008` function as seen below:

```
library(nsRFA)
data <- c(91,84,42,30,66,95,65,12,27,61,31,101,48,52,53,55,80,23,87,46,50,33,75,88,54,17,57,39,10,89,59,24,11,43,13,93,105,28,104,18,103,62,22,58,15,34,74,51,97,44,99,76,14,16,109,92,110,40,78,83,60,49,96,36,32,81,68,20,56,25,63,47,37,29,100,71,106,41,90,70,85,38,19,108,73,102,26,82,98,45,77,35,94,79,86,72,107,21,67,69,64)
MSC <- MSClaio2008(data)
```

it throws this error:

> Error in optim(par = Tm1, fn = .logLgam, x = x) : object 'Tm1' not found

I have searched for topics on this platform, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801299/error-in-optim-l-bfgs-b-needs-finite-value-of-fn) but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: Show us all the code.

Comment: Please, that's all that is there for my code to work. It was as the example they gave on the web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the package, but it is related to the fact that your data are weird. This function is supposedly fitting distributions to observations of hydrological extremes: you have given it an integer sequence from 10 to 110.

As it turns out, when computing the fit for some of the possible distributions (`P3` and `GEV`, I think), the function internally computes the *skewness* of the data and has a test for what to do if it the skewness is positive *or* negative. It doesn't consider the possibility that the skewness would be exactly 0!

Inside `nsRFA:::ML_estimation`:

```r
skx <- sum((x - mean(x))^3)/(length(x) * sd(x)^3)
if (skx > 0) {
    Tm1 <- min(x) - 1
    ...
} else if (skx < 0) {
    Tm1 <- max(x) + 1
    ...
}
```

If the skewness is exactly zero, then the variable `Tm1` doesn't get set and the next step that relies on `Tm1` breaks.

If you perturb the data in some way so that the skewness is not exactly zero, this should work, e.g. `MSClaio2008(c(8,data))` or `MSClaio2008(data+rnorm(length(data), sd=0.001))` ...

It's a weird case, but it would be worth contacting the maintainer (`maintainer("nsRFA")`) to let them know.

Comment: Thanks so much for the edit and reply. Your answer worked for me and I have a lot from explanations. But I have seen something weird. My data length was 101, when I reduced it to 100, it worked perfectly. I don't why but it worked.

Comment: because you created a data set that was not perfectly symmetrical/unskewed.

Comment: if this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it